# Relatório no IREPORT - STATUS

Tags: java, ireport

Bom dia , preciso alterar um relatório no IREPORT que hoje funciona asim:

Atualmente o campo funciona assim:

```
    (Boolean)
    $F{documentoVigente} ? "VIGENTE" : "VENCIDO"
```

Tenho um text chamado  $F{documentoVigente} passando uma expression class (java String)

Preciso que meu relatorio seja gerado assim hoje:

```
        if $F{dataVencimento} = $F{CurrentDate} : "VIGENTE"
        if else $F{dataVencimento} < $F{CurrentDate} : "VENCIDO"
        else : "VENCENDO" > a data do dia
```

Tenho uma classe que faz referencia a esse relatorio:

```
public  class  RepDtoReport  implement Serizable {

private String nomeRepresentante;
private Integer cartaoAssinatura;
private String descricaoGrupo;
private String codigoPessoa;
private String descricaoCargo;
private String descricaoDocumento;
private Date dataAtualizacao;

private  Date   dataVencimento;

private boolean documentoVigente;


}getts e setters}

public boolean is documentoVigente() {
return documentoVigente;
}

public void setDocumentoVigente (final boolean documentoVigente){
this.documentoVigente = documentoVigente;
}

public  Date getDataVencimento() {
return dataVencimento;
}

public void setDocumentoVigente (final Date dataVencimento ){
this.dataVencimento = dataVencimento;
}
```

Hoje ele esta assim:
[image: Relatorio]

Consigo fazer apenas no ireport ?

Comment: Essa é a melhor forma de fazer esse tipo de comparação, acredito que seu field documentoVigente esteja vindo com um valor falso ou null. Ele é do tipo Boolean né?

Comment: Ele e do tipo boolean, caso eu precisasse colocar mais um valor como ficaria?

Comment: ai vc faz a operação ternaria aninhada, exemplo $F{minhaCondicao1} ? "meu_resultado" : $F{minhaCondicao2} ? "meu_resultado2" : "meu_outro_resultado2"

Comment: Certo, eu tenho uma condicao boolean e preciso  que nesse mesmo campo seja adicionando  o valor Em dia por exemplo, crio mais uma como boolean? e ele vai comparar as 3 e trazer a que necessito?

Answer (score 0):

Eu tenho uma prática que gosto muito de usar. Na geração de relatórios, gosto de separar processamento de dados para o banco e IO para a aplicação.
Pensando nesse sentido, quando você faz uma consulta no banco e traz uma N de registros, ao oferecer isso para a camada de aplicação a mesma precisa iterar em cada um dos registros para aplicar a regra.

Exemplo: Uma consulta que retorna 100 registros acaba processando estes mesmo 100 para chegar ao resultado desejado aplicando as regras do relatório.

Minha dica pra você é analisar a viabilidade de utilizar uma VIEW já com todas as regras necessárias ao seu relatório. Óbvio que desatrela regras da aplicação tem seus ônus e bônus, porém há um ganho enorme em processamento que pode ser uma vantagem, sem contar a facilidade de implementar em qualquer ferramenta de Report.

Comment: Entendo essa lógica mas infelizmente já e uma aplicação em produção e não posso alterar alguns pacotes.